# React работа с JSON перебором

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, функции, перебор

Есть данные, в формате **json**, на **втором скриншоте у меня всё хорошо** получается, я отображаю свойство title, чтобы на сайте был список тем. Но вот **на третьем скриншоте как я не пытался, я не могу понять**, как прописать функцию, чтобы такая же была генерация. Для примера какое отображение мне нужно, я написал всё в статичном **HTML**. **Пожалуйста, помогите, у меня завтра дедлайн** по сдаче этого проекта, а мне только это осталось доделать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В следующий раз публикуйте код как текст, а не как скриншоты, т.к. не все с компьютера заходят на сайт, а также есть небольшая проблема с копированием кода с избражений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
anwver.map((value) => {
    return <label>
        {value}
        <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
})
```

теперь массив anwver содержит реакт элементы. в функции genereteQuestion можно его просто возвращать, а в функции reander допилить оболочку. получается компонент ровно на один вопрос. советую почитать про методы массивов больше https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods

Comment: Спасибо, ты помог разобраться что и как, а то в запаре ничего не понять

Comment: всегда пожалуйста